# jQuery add row number with input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add auto numbering on the first column.
How can I have _no keep adding +1 everytime button Submit is hitted?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn-add").click(function () {
                var _no =  1;
                var _name = $('input[name="addname"]').val();
                var _math = $('input[name="math"]').val();
                var _physic = $('input[name="physic"]').val();
                var _chemistry = $('input[name="chemistry"]').val();
                var _calavrg = "?";
                var _tr = '<tr> <td>' + _stt + '</td> <td>' + _name + '</td> <td>' + _math + '</td> <td>' + _physic + '</td> <td>' + _chemistry + '</td> <td>' + _calcdtb + '</td> </tr>';
                $("#inputtab").append(_tr);
            });
        });
```

And HTML:

```
 <button type="submit" id="btn-add">Submit</button>
 <div class="tab" align="center" style="padding-top: 10px">
            <table id="inputtab" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Math</th>
                <th>Physics</th>
                <th>Chemistry</th>
                <th>Average</th>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Every jQuery collection has a `.length` property that tells you how many elements are in that collection. Every `<table>` has a [`.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) property that also tells you via its `.length` property how many rows there are in that table.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `_no`.  But to have it increase, move it outside the .click handler and inside use `_no++;`

Comment: .....or if it still does not work - add your complete HTML relevant to this jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what `_stt` refers to but probably you're trying something like this?

```js
    var _no = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btn-add").click(function () {
        var _name = $('input[name="addname"]').val();
        var _math = $('input[name="math"]').val();
        var _physic = $('input[name="physic"]').val();
        var _chemistry = $('input[name="chemistry"]').val();
        var _calavrg = "?";
        var _tr = '<tr> <td>' + _no + '</td> <td>' + _name + '</td> <td>' + _math + '</td> <td>' + _physic + '</td> <td>' + _chemistry + '</td> <td>' + _calcdtb + '</td> </tr>';
        $("#inputtab").append(_tr);
        _no++;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I was renaming _stt to _no. This's exactly what I'm looking for. I was so confused. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I would appreciate if you mark this as accepted answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to _calavrg, cause is not defined.
use .on('click).